# phpexcel not working in cakephp 1.3

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3, phpexcel

I am trying to create and download excel file using PHPExcel in my CakePHP 1.3 application, But its not working.
My code:-

```
App::import('Vendor', 'PHPExcel', array('file' => 'Classes/PHPExcel.php'));
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

// Set document properties
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Maarten Balliauw")
->setLastModifiedBy("Maarten Balliauw")
->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
->setDescription("Test document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.")
->setKeywords("office 2007 openxml php")
->setCategory("Test result file");


// Add some data
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello')
->setCellValue('B2', 'world!')
->setCellValue('C1', 'Hello')
->setCellValue('D2', 'world!');

// Miscellaneous glyphs, UTF-8
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
->setCellValue('A4', 'Miscellaneous glyphs')
->setCellValue('A5', 'Miscellaneous glyphs');

// Rename worksheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');


// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
// If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

// If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

No error is coming while downloading. It just downloading a blank file.

It is working (creating and downloading properly) in core PHP but not working in CakePHP 1.3.

Answer (score 0):

step1: Download from (http://www.codeplex.com/PHPExcel) and place it under app\vendors\Classes. Also make sure you place file containing class PHPExcel out side the directory. so your classes directory will have 1 folder and one file.

step2: create a CSV file in view page in the location views/view_name/csv.

step 3: Inside this folder create a file.

e.g.

```
<?php
echo "ID, Property ID, Date,  Status \n";
foreach($x as $y) {
    echo $y['Incident']['id'] . ',';
    echo $y['Incident']['name'] . ',';
    echo $y['Incident']['date'] .',';
    echo $y['Incident']['status'];
    echo "\n";
}
```

Step4: Provide proper link in any view where you are calling.

Answer (score 0):

Use the link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37072809/2281448

NB: The above answer is for CakePHP 2.0. But the only difference is in the folder structure which is given below.
Place the folder 'Classes' into your Cakephp folder 'app/vendors/PHPExcel'.