# How we can use code for PHPExcel in controller in cakephp 3?

Tags: cakephp, controller, phpexcel

If we install PHPExcel in cakephp,then how we can use it in controller?

Comment: What have you tried so far? As it stands your question is too broad for Stack Overflow and shows no effort.

Answer (score 0):

The question is already asked in an another thread, you can see here : [Using PHPExcel in CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14773283/using-phpexcel-in-cakephp)

More detailed explanation from CakePHP documentation is here : http://bakery.cakephp.org/2012/04/02/PhpExcel-helper-for-generating-excel-files.html